# How to rotate a plane 90 degrees, with texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to build an fps game, but when I go to rotate the floor anywhere close to 90 degrees it just vanishes from the scene.
Here's the code responsible for the plane.

```
var colorMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/textures/wood_albedo.png');

var radian = 2 * Math.PI *(90 / 360);
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20);

var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 'white', side: THREE.DoubleSide});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider accepting and upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, as I assume you are mapping the image to the plane behind the scenes. The only thing I would check is that `2 * Math.PI * (90 / 360)` is the same thing as `Math.PI / 2`. Another thing you should check is that instead of white, it would be ideal to use a shade of grey for the map.

Your problem could have a simple solution - your rotation is making the plane parallel to the camera, making it invisible. You should typically keep your rotations in terms of `Math.PI`.
Let me know if you have any further questions on this.

Tip: Adding a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) link could help greatly debug your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll check that as soon as possible. And as far as jsfiddle, I’m actually using replit, but I can get a link if this doesn’t solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah, replit works too. If it still doesn't work, then you should consider taking a look at DAT.GUI, which can easily debug your issue.